# If $G$ is simple with diameter two and maximum degree $|V(G)| - 2$, then $|E(G)| \geq 2|V(G)| - 4$

Tags: graph-theory

This is my try:

Because the diameter of $G$ is two and have maximum degree the number of vertex: $|V(G)| - 2$, where $|V(G)|$ is the number of vertex, then the grade for any vertex in $G$ is greater than or equal to two. And since $\sum \delta(v_i) = |E(G)|$, where $\delta(v_i)$ represents the grade of a vertex in $V(G)$ and $|E(G)|$ the number of edges in $G$, then $\sum \delta(v_i) \geq 2(|V(G)| - 2) = 2|V(G)| - 4$.

Comment: $\sum \delta (v_i)$ counts each edge twice, that is, $\sum \delta (v_i)=2\cdot |E(G)|$.

Comment: @bof I guess grade=degree=valency of a vertex, that is, the number of edges at the vertex.

Comment: @David do you need more help? or is it clear now?

Comment: Yes @DKal. I'm thinking how to repair my proof.

Comment: How do you know the degree of any vertex is at least $2$?

Comment: Because, if $v$ not adjacent with $w$, then (because the diameter is two) exist $u$, such that $u$ is adjacent with $v$ and $w$. @bof

Comment: That proves that there **is** a vertex of degree at least $2$. A slightly more complicated argument will be needed to show that **every** vertex has degree at least $2$. You will have to **use** the assumption that the maximum degree is equal to $|V(G)|-2$. Diameter $2$ is not enough; the star $K_{1,n}$ has diameter $2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G$ be a graph of diameter $2$ and order $n=|V(G)|$, and suppose that $G$ has a vertex $v$ of degree $n-2$. It is easy to see that $G-v$ is a connected graph. [There is a vertex $u$ of $G-v$ which is not adjacent to $v$; every other vertex of $G-v$ is connected to $u$ by a path in $G$ of length at most $2$; since there is no edge $uv$, that path must be contained in $G-v$.] Since $G-v$ is a connected graph with $n-1$ vertices, it must have at least $n-2$ edges; added to the $n-2$ edges which are incident with $v$, this makes at least $2n-4$ edges in $G$.

Alternatively, without using the fact that a connected graph on $m$ vertices must have at least $m-1$ edges:

Let $N(x)$ denote the neighborhood of vertex $x$, i.e., the set of all vertices adjacent to $x$. Since $|N(v)|=n-2$, there is a unique vertex $u\in V(G)\setminus[\{v\}\cup N(v)]$. Let $X=              N(v)\setminus N(u)$; so $|X|=n-2-|N(u)|$.Each vertex in $X$ is connected to $u$ by a path of length $2$, therefore, each vertex in $X$ is adjacent to some vertex in $N(u)$. Now there are $ n        -2$ edges incident with $v$, and $|N(u)|$ edges incident with $u$, and at least $|X|$ edges joining vertices in $X$ to vertices in $N(u)$.Hence$$|E(G)|\ge(n-2)+|N(u)|+|X|=(n-2)+|N(u)|+(n-2-|N(u)|)=2n-4.$$

Comment: This exercise is in my book (Bondy & Morty) before cycles, i.e, before connectivity.

Comment: First edition, page 14. @bof